# Ambari Hive, Where Clause

Tags: hive, ambari

I need some help with this Hive Query please.

- Table name is frame_curated
- Column name is Message
- Column type is string

In that column the data is formatted like this:

```
IP":"1735", "ID":"G54X"
```

I'm looking for records where `ID="G54X"` in column Message.

Something like this

`Select * FROM frame_curated WHERE  frame_curated.Message LIKE '%G54X%'`

From my research, I think it should look like this:

```
Select * FROM frame_curated WHERE  frame_curated.Message.ID ['G54X']
```

But its not working.

Your help is sincerely appreciated.

Basil

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `frame_curated.Message.ID ['G54X']` would work for string data type. it could only work if your data type is `List<dict<string:string>>`

you can use something like this

```
select * from temp.test2 where value like '%"ID":%G54X%'
```

The other approach is, you change the table datatype to complex and run the query you suggested.

Comment: I'm too green to arrow up, I appreciate your response. Thanks.